# Minimum number of points to estimate similarity transformation in 3D

Tags: transformation, rigid-transformation

I am studying computer vision and learning about different geometric transformations in 2D and 3D. I understand that the [8-point algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight-point_algorithm#Using_fewer_than_eight_points) requires 8 2D point correspondences to recover the 8 DOF of the fundamental matrix, and given some other information, we can recover with fewer points required.

I also know that 4 corresponding pairs of coplanar 2D points can be used to recover a [homography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography_(computer_vision)) using the DLT.

**Given 3D correspondences, though, what is the minimum number of points required to correctly determine a similarity transform (uniform scale, rotation, and translation) between point sets?**

Intuitively, I would think only 3 non-collinear point correspondences are necessary (and ideally the estimation would happen in a robust way using RANSAC or something similar), but I can't make a DOF argument or the like. Can someone provide the intuition here?

Thanks!

Comment: You need at as many 'knowns' (i.e., point correspondences) as there are 'unknowns'.  In this case, the number of unknowns is the number of parameters (or degrees of freedom) needed to define a 3D affine (or projective or whatever kind you want) transformation.  I believe a 3D affine transform can be encoded as a $4\times 4$ matrix with bottom row $(0,0,0,1)$, leaving an upper bound of 12 degrees of freedom.  You can probably cut down on that number by requiring certain things of your transformation.

Comment: @ChocolateAndCheese: It seems that's the DOF idea, but if you have 3 non-collinear points, you can completely define plane.  Using that to align two planes fixes scale, rotation, and translation though. What more information is needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about it in terms of the degrees of freedom in the transformation. For a composition of a scaled rotation with a translation we have the following degrees of freedom: 3 for the translation, 3 for the rotation (axis and angle), and one more for the uniform scale factor. Each pair of points contributes three equations, so three pairs of points should be more than enough, while two pairs doesn’t quite do it. An appendix to [the paper linked by Peter Sheldrick](http://people.csail.mit.edu/bkph/papers/Absolute_Orientation.pdf) in the comment above describes a straightforward way to compute the transformation given exactly three pairs of points.